# How to achieve conditional nested formatting without multiple allocations?

Tags: rust, formatting

I have a format string consisting of multiple conditional components and I'm looking for a solution that doesn't need multiple allocations of Strings for the intermediate steps. If I create each single component of the final format string with the `format!`-macro then it works but I need an allocation for each component.

I tried experimenting with using only macros to generate the complex format string and its arguments. However, this always resulted in "temporary value is freed at the end of this statement" errors. I tried to use one single buffer of type `impl core::fmt::Write` but I couldn't make success with this either.

On a high level, I want something like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let prefix_include_a = true;
    let prefix_include_b = true;
    // prefix itself is a formatted string and it is further formatted here
    println!("{prefix:<10}{message:>10}!",
        prefix = format_prefix(prefix_include_a, prefix_include_b),
        message = "message"
    );
}

// formats the prefix component of the final string.
// needs multiple String allocations as `format!` is used
fn format_prefix(inc_a: bool, inc_b: bool) -> String {
    format!("[{a:<5}{b:<5}]",
        a = if inc_a {
            format!("{:.1}", 1.234)
        } else {
            format!("")
        },
        b = if inc_b {
            format!("{:.2}", 1.234)
        } else {
            format!("")
        },
    )
}
```

Is this possible with no or only one single allocation?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution is to just `write!` directly to the underlying stream e.g.

```rust
use std::io::{stdout, Write};

fn main() {
    let prefix_include_a = true;
    let prefix_include_b = true;
    
    let mut stdout = stdout();
    let _ = format_prefix(&mut stdout, prefix_include_a, prefix_include_b);
    let _ = write!(stdout, "{:>10}", "message");
}

// formats the prefix component of the final string.
// needs multiple String allocations as `format!` is used
fn format_prefix(mut s: impl Write, inc_a: bool, inc_b: bool) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    write!(s, "[")?;
    if inc_a {
        write!(s, "{:<5.1}", 1.234)?;
    } else {
        write!(s, "     ")?;
    }
    if inc_b {
        write!(s, "{:<5.2}", 1.234)?;
    } else {
        write!(s, "     ")?;
    }
    write!(s, "]")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

An alternative is to reify `prefix` into a type, and implement `Display` for it. I would think (hope?) the formatter is a passthrough to the underlying stream, though I've never actually looked:

```
use std::io::{stdout, Write};

fn main() {
    let prefix_include_a = true;
    let prefix_include_b = true;

    println!(
        "{prefix:<10}{message:>10}!",
        prefix = Prefix(prefix_include_a, prefix_include_b),
        message = "message"
    );
}

struct Prefix(bool, bool);
impl std::fmt::Display for Prefix {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "[")?;
        if self.0 {
            write!(f, "{:<5.1}", 1.234)?;
        } else {
            write!(f, "     ")?;
        }
        if self.1 {
            write!(f, "{:<5.2}", 1.234)?;
        } else {
            write!(f, "     ")?;
        }
        write!(f, "]")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Note: I've not handled the padding of the prefix in either version, though I don't think it makes much sense: both prefix values are padded to 5, so the prefix is always at least 12 wide. Padding to 10 makes no sense.

The prefix object could, however, use the externally specified padding to distribute to internal paddings, if that's desirable. See [`std::fmt::Formatter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html) for information you can obtain about formatting specifiers.

To clean up the conditionals, you could probably use [`format_args!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format_args.html), though I've pretty little experience with that.